# I can not access the right data of property sent from parent to child component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am facing an issue with react and I am totally stuck.  I have 3 components: channel as a parent and header and story as a children:

```
class Channel extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super();
}

componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getChannels();

}

render() {
    return (
        <div>


            <div className="col-xs-12  col-md-8 col-lg-8>
                <div className="row">
                    <Header activeChannelList={this.props.channels.channelsArr}/>
                </div>
                <div className="row">

                    {
                        this.props.channels.channelsArr.map((item, i) =>   <StoryBoard 
                                                                                     newsChanel={item}

                                                                                     key={"storyBoard" + i}
                                                                                    ></StoryBoard>)
                    }
                </div>
            </div>


            <div className="col-xs-12  col-md-2 col-lg-2 color2">.col-sm-4</div>
        </div>

    );
    }
 }
  const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
 return {
    channels: state.channelReducer
    };
  };

   const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
   return {
    getChannels: () => {
        dispatch(getChannels());

        }
      };
    };
  export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Channel);
```

As you can see I have a ajax call with this.props.getChannels(); and I put it in componentDidMount to make sure that it is called before rendering then after I pass the channels to the Header ans story which are children components. 
Now my problem is when I try to access it in Header via  console.log(this.props.activeChannelList); I get 0 thought I should have 5 channels. More intrestingly when I try to access the props I send in Stroryboard I can easily access them without any problem. The following is my code for Header:

```
 export class Header extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super();
}



componentDidMount() {

    console.log("dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd");
    console.log(this.props.activeChannelList);// I get 0 though I should get 5
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="col-xs-12 header tjHeaderDummy">
            <div className="col-xs-1"></div>

        </div>
        );
       }
       }
```

And my storyboard is :

```
class StoryBoard extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super();

}
componentDidMount() {


    if(this.props.isFreshLoad ){
        do sth
    }

}



render() {
    return (
        <div>

        </div>
    );
}


 }

 const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    stories: state.storyBoardReducer
  };
};

 const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
return {
    //some funcs

    }

   };
 };   
 export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(StoryBoard);
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: It's unclear how you can view them in `StoryBoard` component if you don't pass it as a prop (maybe you get it via redux store?). Also, what's inside `this.props.channels.channelsArr` ?

Comment: @OmriAharon I will update my answer :)

Comment: one more thing, u r printing the value in `componentDidMount` method in Header, this method get called only once, if ur api response come after the rendering of Header, it will never print 5, put the console in render method, so that at any time when u get the response it will populate the value.

Comment: @MayankShukla Man u just fixed my issue u are right what I am doing is right but I did not use the right lifecycle. Could you please add it as an answer since I am sure many other developers may face the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U r printing the value in `componentDidMount` method in `Header` component, this `lifecycle` method get called only once, if ur api response come after the rendering of Header, it will never print 5, put the console in render method, so that at any time when u get the response it will populate the value.

From Docs:

> componentDidMount: is invoked immediately after a component is mounted
>   first time. This is where AJAX requests and DOM or state updates
>   should occur.

Try this Header Comp, it will print the proper value:

```
export class Header extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super();
    }

    componentDidMount() {

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="col-xs-12">
               {this.props.activeChannelList}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: or you can use componentWillReceiveProps as explained here : https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/update/component_will_receive_props.html